# Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x), : 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I'm trying to visualize the results in R.

This part of the code is:

```
fit=sampling(m,data=stan_data,iter=4000,warmup=2000,chains=8,thin=4,control = list(adapt_delta = 0.90, max_treedepth = 10))   
out = rstan::extract(fit)  
prediction = out$prediction  
estimated.deaths = out$E_deaths.  
estimated.deaths.cf = out$E_deaths0
library(bayesplot)  
filename <- paste0('base-',JOBID)  
plot_labels <- c("School Closure",
                 "Self Isolation",
                 "Public Events",
                 "First Intervention",
                 "Lockdown", 'Social distancing')  
alpha = (as.matrix(out$alpha))
```

After running the last line, the error occurs:

> Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  :
> 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @jogo Thank you. I tried your suggestion and the error is still there. 'out' is as below:   out = rstan::extract(fit)

Comment: fit = sampling(m,data=stan_data,iter=4000,warmup=2000,chains=8,thin=4,control = list(adapt_delta = 0.90, max_treedepth = 10))

Comment: in your example is no object `stan_data`. Please edit your question! Give a [mre] in your question!